# ReplaceText processor configuration

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I am not that good in regex.
What would be the proper configuration to do the following;

1. Remove backslash from text.
2. Replace "{  with {
3. replace }" with }

Basically I need to clean escaped JSON.

Like before:

```
 "{\"hashtags\":[{\"text\":\"Apple\",\"indices\":[45,51]}],\"urls\":[{\"url\":\"\",\"expanded_url\":\"\",\"display_url\":\"owler.us/abdLas\",\"indices\":[64,87]}],\"user_mentions\":[],\"symbols\":[{\"text\":\"AAPL\",\"indices\":[88,93]}]}",
```

after:

```
{"hashtags":[{"text":"Apple","indices":[45,51]}],"urls":[{"url":"","expanded_url":"","display_url":"owler.us/abdLas","indices":[64,87]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[{"text":"AAPL","indices":[88,93]}]},
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) apache-nifi supports JAVA regex..So you can use `replaceAll("\\"([{}])", "$1")` and `replaceAll("\\", "")`

Comment: @rock321987 I set search value as \"([{}]) and replacement value as $1 and it adds 2 backslashes instead of removing.  {"tag":"\"{\\\"hashtags\\\":[],\\\"urls\\\":[{\\\"url\\\"...

Comment: sorry..you should use `replaceAll("\\\"([{}])", "$1")` and `replaceAll("\\\\", "")`

Comment: update me after trying

Comment: @rock321987 Should I use both or one of these?

Comment: first use any one and see if its working? then you can use both together

Comment: @rock321987 I used first one and it added backslashes.

Comment: Did you try `replaceAll("\\\"([{}])", "$1")`??its working in **[java](http://ideone.com/aBSwVS)**

Comment: @rock321987 I am a bit confused.  Processor has 2 properties: Search value and replacement value. What should I put and where?

Comment: I don't have much idea but you have to use replacement..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110071/discussion-between-rock321987-and-igor-k).

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion from NiFi user group worked fine:
3 ReplaceText  processors one after another:

1. Search value : \
   Replace value : Empty string set

2.
Search value : "{
Replace value : {

3.
Search value : }"
Replace value : }

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
replaceAll("\"[{]", "{");
replaceAll("[}]\"", "}");
```

There's no need to escape this backslash because it's not a regex backslash.

## Explanation

- The `\"` matches a literal `"`.
- The `[}]` matches a `}`. I have chosen to use brackets instead of the evil Java escaped escape.